# Enhancing all images in a folder

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation

In Adobe Photoshop there are the options to auto tone, auto contrast and auto color. Is there a way to automatically apply all 3 of the operations to all images in a folder? I'm using Photo shop 2014 on Windows 8.1 (64bit).

Answer (score 1):

Try "Batch-Process" in Photoshop:

1. Do one of the following: Choose File > Automate > Batch (Photoshop)

   Choose Tools > Photoshop > Batch (Bridge)
2. Specify the action you want to use to process files from the Set and
   Action pop-up menus. The menus display actions available in the
   Actions panel. You may need to choose a different set or load a set
   in the panel if you don’t see your action.
3. Choose the files to process from the Source pop-up menu:

   **Folder**
   Processes files in a folder you specify. Click Choose to locate and
   select the folder.

   **Import**
   Processes images from a digital camera, scanner, or a PDF document.

   **Opened Files**
   Processes all open files.

   **Bridge**
   Processes selected files in Adobe Bridge. If no files are selected,
   the files in the current Bridge folder are processed.

[source](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)